# How to prove the identity $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{{H_{n}}^2}{n^2} = \dfrac{17}{360} {\pi}^4$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation, harmonic-numbers

> **Prove That**
>
> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{{H_{n}}^2}{n^2} = \dfrac{17}{360} {\pi}^4$$

I encountered this identity while reading the article about [Harmonic Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) on Wikipedia. I thought of using the integral representation of Harmonic Number, but the square is creating trouble.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the provided reference (from the linked Wolfram article): [*On an Intriguing Integral and Some Series Related to $\zeta(4)$*](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2160718?seq=1), David Borwein and Jonathan M. Borwein. Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society, Vol. 123, No. 4 (Apr., 1995), pp. 1191-1198.